# Finding the summation of these two Infinite Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image: The questions:]

I find the sequence of partial sums, but I cannot find the general term. I know once I find the general term of the sequence of partial sums, I take the limit of that and that number is the sum of the series. I just cannot find a pattern in either of these.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hints : Partial fraction decomposition and geometric series

Comment: The first can be written as a telescoping series.  The second can be writen as the sum of two distinct geometric series.  Can you wrap it up?

Comment: Thank you for your hints, it's so easy once you know how to do it!

Comment: @user357335 Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Note that

- $\sum \frac{2}{n^2+4n+3}=\sum \frac{1}{n+1}-\sum\frac{1}{n+3}$ and many terms cancel out
- $\sum \frac{1+2^n}{3^n}=\sum \left(\frac13\right)^n+\sum \left(\frac23\right)^n$ and refer to geometric series

Comment: It's so easy omg how did I not think to do this? THANK YOU!

Comment: @user357335 Yes the second is really strightforward,the first is a little more tricky. You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the comment hint, write the first sum as
$$
\sum \left(\frac{A}{n+B} - \frac{C}{n+D}\right)
$$
and apply telescoping series. For the second one note that
$$
\frac{1+2^n}{3^n} = \frac{1}{3^n} + \frac{2^n}{3^n} = (1/3)^n + (2/3)^n
$$